# Wrong answer in the Jacobian of cosine function with Octave symbolic

Tags: octave

The following lines on Octave

```
>> syms x1 x2
>> jacobian([cos(x1-x2)])
ans = (sym) [-sin(x1 - x2)  sin(x1 - x2)]  (1x2 matrix)
>> jacobian([cos(x2-x1)])
ans = (sym) [-sin(x1 - x2)  sin(x1 - x2)]  (1x2 matrix)
```

gives me the same answer. That's wrong!!! How can I work around this issue?

Regards

Hugo

Comment: Why is it wrong? `cos(x)==cos(-x)`, so the two inputs are the same, and therefore they should have the same Jacobean.

Comment: Yep. I saw my mistake after posting. Thx for the reply

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.